# mysql if Syntax ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, if-statement

I'm trying to create a procedure on mysql, it's not too hard, but when using "if" the things goes crazy, it says there's a error but i cant understand. Here it goes:

```
CREATE SP_Verify_DATE (IN comp INT,IN prod INT,IN qt INT)
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(cd_compra) INTO @tes FROM produto_compra WHERE cd_produto=prod AND cd_compra=comp;

IF (@tes = 1) THEN

UPDATE produto_compra WHERE cd_produto=prod AND cd_compra=comp SET qt_produto = qt_produto + qt;
ELSE 

INSERT INTO produto_compra VALUES(comp,prod,qt);

END IF;

END
```

Many thanks to peterm !!! works !!!! what i lost 2 night's trying to find the error, and your ideia is better than my procedure i used it, thanks again !

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You have to use `CREATE PROCEDURE` instead of just `CREATE`;
2. Your `UPDATE` syntax was wrong. `SET` goes before `WHERE` clause.
3. You need change `DELIMITER`

Try

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Verify_DATE (IN comp INT, IN prod INT, IN qt INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(cd_compra) 
    INTO @tes 
    FROM produto_compra 
   WHERE cd_produto=prod 
     AND cd_compra=comp;

  IF (@tes = 1) THEN
    UPDATE produto_compra
       SET qt_produto = qt_produto + qt
     WHERE cd_produto=prod AND cd_compra=comp;
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO produto_compra VALUES(comp,prod,qt);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Other than that your code is OK.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c10a6/1)** demo

---

Now you can boil down the whole thing to just one insert statement if you have or if you define a unique index on `(cd_produto, cd_compra)` (and following the logic of your code you should have such constraint) using [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Verify_DATE (IN comp INT, IN prod INT, IN qt INT)
  INSERT INTO produto_compra (cd_produto, cd_compra, qt_produto)
  VALUES(comp, prod, qt)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qt_produto = qt_produto + VALUES(qt_produto);
```

*Since it's a one-statement SP now you don't even need to use `BEGIN ... END` block and change delimiter.*

Obviously if you need to you can opt-out from a stored procedure completely and use such insert statement on its own.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb4bce/2)** demo